# sectioned table view returning blank table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I found code examples online for creating a tableview with alphabetical sections and i have tried to adapt for my tableview.

However, now the simulator is returning a blank table.

I've obviously gone wrong, anyone mind pointing out the mistakes?
Every change I make doesn't help.
Thank you

```
#import "RCViewController.h"

@interface RCViewController ()

@end

@implementation RCViewController

@synthesize content = _content;

@synthesize sectionData;
@synthesize sectionNames;


-(NSArray *)content {
NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tee", @"Club", @"Green", @"Putt", nil];
NSArray *sortedWords = [words     sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSString *currentLetter = @"";

for (NSString *string in sortedWords) {
    if (string.length>0) {
        NSString *letter = [string substringToIndex:1];

        if (![letter isEqualToString:currentLetter]) {
            [sectionNames addObject:letter];
            currentLetter = letter;

            NSMutableArray *oneSection = [NSMutableArray array];
            [sectionData addObject:oneSection];
            [[sectionData lastObject]addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
return _content;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return sectionNames.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


return [[sectionData objectAtIndex:section]count];

}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [sectionNames objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return sectionNames;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"simpleTableIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    cell.textLabel.text =[[self.sectionData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Well that `content` method looks dodgy.  Firstly you don't want all that processing everytime it's called (I assume that it's called more than once) and what is populating `_content`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things that are not optimal with your code but what is causing the table to be blank is most likely that you are never populating sectionData and sectionName and so it returns a table with no section names or section data. Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tee", @"Club", @"Green", @"Putt", nil];
NSArray *sortedWords = [words     sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSString *currentLetter = @"";

for (NSString *string in sortedWords) {
    if (string.length>0) {
        NSString *letter = [string substringToIndex:1];

        if (![letter isEqualToString:currentLetter]) {
            [sectionNames addObject:letter];
            currentLetter = letter;

            NSMutableArray *oneSection = [NSMutableArray array];
            [sectionData addObject:oneSection];
            [[sectionData lastObject]addObject:string];
        }
    }
}
}
```